# Redirect http to https and remove .html from pages

Tags: .htaccess

I'm very unfamiliar with how `.htaccess` to be honest, but what I'm trying to accomplish is that:

1. All http requests redirect to https
2. All pages remove the `.html` from the URL

I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I keep getting an error in Chrome:

> example.com redirected you too many times.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please give examples of the URLs you are requesting. Do all URLs map directly to `.html` files by simply appending `.html`? Try disabling `MultiViews`. ie. `Options -MultiViews` at the top of your file.

Comment: Related cross-site post: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109680/htacess-remove-html-from-the-homepage-but-not-from-folders-within-within-tha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yoursite.com/$1 [L,R]

#the rules above will redirect the entire site into https without www unless the request come with https://www .      

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

#the rules above will remove any .HTML.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

 # you can use the two lines if file without extension not work and you want to map them to .html files and if you want to go the same file .html without extension keep it as it is .
```