# Error while removing .html from URL using .htaccess?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url

I needed to remove .html from all urls on my website. The trick is - all pages and subpages were OK except one. One page was just showing me "Error 404 mot found" Now I'm trying to understand how is that possible if before all pages were working perfectly before and removing .html were performed for all pages at once. Tried different combinations actually - all ended up with the same result. I assume it may be a problem with the page but what kind of problem and where do I look for it?  Will appreciate any help.

Was using following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Could it be that you are looking at a cached result? Always test with a fresh anonymous browser window and use "deep reloads", not just reloads. If that is not the issue then you will need to start debugging. The apache http server's rewriting module allows to log what is going on inside the rewriting engine. I suggest you start by reading the documentation of the tool you are using for that: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteLog

Comment: i was thinking so, so i tried anonymous browser right away but it didn't help. I thought it may be problem with the page itself

Comment: If those are really "just" plain html files then there is nothing that could be wrong with those files that would lead to a 404. That error indicates that the requested resource does not exist (as you probably read). So either the file does not exist (which you certainly tripple checked, uncluding the spelling), or the routing inside the http server is wrong (which is surprising considering that you only implemented general rewriting rules). So you will need to start debugging, we cannot do that for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try the folwoing rules :

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

The details in my previous answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457844/5255593

If it is ok , replace `R=302` with `R=301` to be permanent

Comment: Same thing. All pages are working except one. Also what's interesting - if i manually type address of subpage (this page has 6 subpages) i can get in on the subpage. But this very page doesn't work. Says too many redirects.